# C++ 11 using hinnant date library date::parse with full timezone name?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-chrono

I have a time and date, and I know my full timezone name, and I want to convert it to sys_seconds:

```
#include <date/tz.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace date;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string sToParse = "2020-04-17T09:30:00American/Chicago";
  std::cout << "raw: " << sToParse << endl;
  static const std::string dateTimeFormat { "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z" };
  istringstream ss{ sToParse };
  sys_seconds dt;
  ss >> parse(dateTimeFormat, dt);
  std::cout << dt << '\n';
  std::cout << dt.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
  auto berlin = make_zoned("Europe/Berlin", dt);
  auto local  = make_zoned("America/Chicago", dt);
  auto utc2   = make_zoned("America/Denver", dt);
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", dt) << '\n';
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", berlin) << '\n';
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", local) << '\n';
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", utc2) << '\n';
}
```

It parses the time, but is not using the timezone name provided, but rather UTC.  What am I missing?

I did try use chrono, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The big picture is that `%Z` is normally treated as the time zone abbreviation, not the IANA time zone name.  And unfortunately there's not a reliable way to turn an abbreviation into a UTC offset.

So when you parse using `%Z` as you're doing, although a name does get parsed, that name is treated as an abbreviation and does not impact the value parsed (no UTC offset is applied).

The second thing to know is that `sys_seconds` has the semantics of UTC.  Your code is parsing `"2020-04-17T09:30:00"` and treating it as a UTC timestamp, and then parsing `"American/Chicago"` because of the `%Z`, and then ignoring that string.

However, this can be fixed.

First, parse into a `local_seconds` instead of a `sys_seconds`.  This will treat `"2020-04-17T09:30:00"` as a local time for some as yet unknown time zone.

Next, recover the parsed `"American/Chicago"` into a `string`.  This is done by supplying a `string` as the last argument in the call to `parse`.  Then you can pair the `local_seconds` and the `string` to make a `zoned_time`.

This all looks like:

```
#include <date/tz.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace date;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string sToParse = "2020-04-17T09:30:00America/Chicago";
  std::cout << "raw: " << sToParse << endl;
  static const std::string dateTimeFormat { "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z" };
  istringstream ss{ sToParse };
  local_seconds dt;
  string tz_name;
  ss >> parse(dateTimeFormat, dt, tz_name);
  std::cout << dt << '\n';
  std::cout << dt.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
  auto local  = make_zoned(tz_name, dt);
  auto berlin = make_zoned("Europe/Berlin", local);
  auto utc2   = make_zoned("UTC", local);
  std::cout << format("%F %T", dt) << '\n';
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", berlin) << '\n';
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", local) << '\n';
  std::cout << format("%F %T %Z", utc2) << '\n';
}
```

- Corrected spelling in `"America/Chicago"`.
- Changed type of `dt` from `sys_seconds` to `local_seconds`.
- Added new variable `string tz_name;` and passed that into `parse`.
- Used `dt` and `tz_name` in `make_zoned` to create `local`.
- Removed `%Z` in when formatting `dt` as a `local_time` has no time zone associated with it.  Failure to do this results in a run-time error within the call to `format`.
- Used `local` as the "time point" in creating other `zoned_time`s.

Output:

```
raw: 2020-04-17T09:30:00America/Chicago
2020-04-17 09:30:00
1587115800s
2020-04-17 09:30:00
2020-04-17 16:30:00 CEST
2020-04-17 09:30:00 CDT
2020-04-17 14:30:00 UTC
```

Comment: That works perfect.  I just found your answer from last year:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574407/problem-parsing-date-time-with-timezone-name-using-howard-hinnants-library